# MongoDB package has not been found installed

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working on a NestJs app which uses MongoDB (mongoose). It used to work, but some how out of the blue it stopped. The only thing that has happend is a `npm i`.

The error is:

```
DriverPackageNotInstalledError: MongoDB package has not been found installed. Try to install it: npm install mongodb --save
    at MongoDriver.loadDependencies 
(/Users/jeanluca/dev/api/src/driver/mongodb/MongoDriver.ts:531:19)
at new MongoDriver 
(/Users/jeanluca/dev/api/src/driver/mongodb/MongoDriver.ts:237:14)
at DriverFactory.create 
(/Users/jeanluca/dev/api/src/driver/DriverFactory.ts:60:24)
at new DataSource (/Users/jeanluca/api/src/data- 
source/DataSource.ts:139:43)
at createTypeormDataSource 
(/Users/jeanluca/dev/api/node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm/di
...
```

My app.module.ts looks like:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath, isGlobal: true }),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({ useClass: TypeOrmConfigService }),
        ApiModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see I have a class `TypeOrmConfigService` which creates the database config:

```
@Injectable()
export class TypeOrmConfigService implements TypeOrmOptionsFactory {
  @Inject(ConfigService)
  private readonly config: ConfigService;

  public createTypeOrmOptions(): TypeOrmModuleOptions {
      return {
          type: 'mongodb',
          host: this.config.get<string>('DATABASE_HOST'), // 127.0.0.1
          port: this.config.get<number>('DATABASE_PORT'),
          database: this.config.get<string>('DATABASE_NAME'), 
          username: this.config.get<string>('DATABASE_USER'),
          password: this.config.get<string>('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
          logging: true,
          logger: 'file',
          synchronize: false, // never use TRUE in production!
          authSource: 'admin',
          ssl: false,
          autoLoadEntities: true // Fix NX monorepo build issue with `entity` generation
};
```

}
}

and the relevant package.json snippet:

```
"@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^2.3.1",
"@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.2",
"@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.3",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
"mongoose": "^7.0.1",
"passport": "^0.6.0",
"passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
```

Any suggestions what might cause this error?

Comment: do you tried  delete node_modules then run npm install?

Comment: I think it has to do with that. But I removed node_modules many times without success. The error just went away after I changed the mongoose version to 6. And now the error is also gone with 7 again. So I guess that deleting node_modules wasn't enough, I also should've cleared the cache!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the *Installation* section [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm), you need to install mongodb driver to be able to use Typeorm with MongoDB.

```
npm install mongodb
```